# How to get the date from foreign Key column in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new to Django.I have two tables `StatusTable` and `SystemTable` in where the SystemTable has a foreign column "Status" where is stores the id of the status from StatusTable.The data save is working fine as expected. I need to show the Statusname of the system in a Statuspage but instead I am getting only the id of the status stored in SystemTable.

**Models.py**

```
class StatusTable(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

    class SystemTable(models.Model):
       sid = models.CharField(max_length=3)
       status = models.ForeignKey(StatusTable,null=True)
```

**Viwes.py**

```
def systemstatuspage(request):
    form = CreateTaskMaster()        
    task_title = SystemTable.objects.all()
    my_list = [ model_to_dict(x) for x in task_title]

    return render(request, 'task/task.html', {'form': form, 'sid':my_list})
```

[image]

Comment: You haven't post your TaskMaster model.

Comment: Maybe `SystemTable.get(id=id_i_am_getting).status.status` (You should not name fields with same name, so you dont have this kind of weird statment).

Anyway, in the view are you using a TaskMaster model?

Comment: Sorry Jose ..Its not TaskMaster its SystemTable..can you help me with the query

Comment: @MohamedNaveen if you have a ForeignKey in a Model you can access it like an attribute. ie a SystemTable object will have an attribute `status` refering to a StatusTable row. I missed the `objects` in the previous comment statment. Something like `status_table_row = SystemTable.objects.get(sid=system_sid).status` now you can access the name by `status_table_row.status_name`. You can look at [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to convert queryset to list manually, you can loop queryset in your template.

```
def systemstatuspage(request):
    form = CreateTaskMaster()        
    tasks = SystemTable.objects.all()
    # remove this line
    # my_list = [ model_to_dict(x) for x in task_title]
    return render(request, 'task/task.html', {'form': form, 's_ids':tasks})
```

and in template you can use foreign-key relation

```
{% for s in s_ids %}
   {{s.status.status_name}}
{% endfor %}
```